# How to get cross join result from inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Question from my last interview - Can we get cross join result from inner join without using cross join statement in sql server ?

Comment: yes, of course, just use a join condition that's always true: `SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON 1=1`

Comment: @Lamak it is working thamks

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already there in comment,

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON 1=1
```